# Contraction of a third order tensor

Tags: tensor-products

Let $$\overrightarrow{a}=a_i \overrightarrow e_i,\overrightarrow b=b_j \overrightarrow e_j,\overrightarrow v=v_k \overrightarrow e_k$$

I want to calculate the contraction:
$cont_{23}(\overrightarrow a \otimes  \overrightarrow b\otimes\overrightarrow v)$
The answer which I know is :
$$cont_{23}(\overrightarrow a \otimes  \overrightarrow b\otimes\overrightarrow v)= a_ib_jv_j\overrightarrow e_i=( \overrightarrow b \cdot \overrightarrow v) \overrightarrow a$$ which seems reasonable because contraction of a third order tensor is a first order tensor (contraction reduces the order by 2).

A procedure is given to me like this as we apply contraction to an arbitrary vector $\overrightarrow w$ ? is this sound reasonable and how from this we can get the answer to the original question?

$$cont_{23}(\overrightarrow a \otimes  \overrightarrow b\otimes\overrightarrow v)=  cont_{23}(\overrightarrow a \otimes  \overrightarrow b\otimes\overrightarrow v)(\overrightarrow w)=(\overrightarrow a \otimes  \overrightarrow b\otimes\overrightarrow v)(\overrightarrow w\otimes\overrightarrow e_l\otimes \overrightarrow e_l)$$

$$=(a_i \overrightarrow e_i \otimes  b_j \overrightarrow e_j\otimes v_k \overrightarrow e_k )(\overrightarrow w\otimes\overrightarrow e_l\otimes \overrightarrow e_l)$$ $$=a_ib_jv_k \overrightarrow e_i \otimes  \overrightarrow e_j\otimes  \overrightarrow e_k (\overrightarrow w\otimes\overrightarrow e_l\otimes \overrightarrow e_l)=a_ib_jv_k \overrightarrow e_i(\overrightarrow w)\overrightarrow e_j(\overrightarrow e_l)\overrightarrow e_k(\overrightarrow e_l)$$
$$=a_ib_jv_k\{\overrightarrow e_i \cdot \overrightarrow w \} \{\overrightarrow e_j\cdot \overrightarrow e_l \} \{\overrightarrow e_k\cdot\overrightarrow e_l\}$$

$$=a_i b_jv_k w_i \delta_{jl} \delta_{kl}=a_i b_jv_k w_i \delta_{jk}=a_i b_jv_jw_i $$
Note:Backgrounds information:Continuum Mechanics and Thermodynamics: From Fundamental Concepts to Governing Equations, by Ellad B. Tadmor, Ronald E. Miller and Ryan S. Elliott